# Cordova, Android and gapless / seamless looping of sound

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have tried multiple ways to get gapless / seamless looping in Android.

I have tried cordova's default Media plugin. I have tried NativeAudio plugin (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio).

They all produce a noticeable gap between loops.

Is there any plugin that does not do that? Some of my sounds are as short as 4 seconds (rain for example) and the gaps ruin the whole playback.

```
// Cordova's Media plugin:
var loop = function (status) {
    if (status === Media.MEDIA_STOPPED) {
        my_media.play();
    }
};

function playAudio(src) {
    my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError, loop);

    my_media.play();
}

// NativeAudio:
window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop('sound');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this plugin instead : https://github.com/SidneyS/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

I think this part of your code is responsible for the gaps :

```
var loop = function (status) {
    if (status === Media.MEDIA_STOPPED) {
        my_media.play();
    }
};
```

Because the loops already work without it, thus you can ask twice to play the music.

I suggest to use the demo code which include a loop : https://github.com/SidneyS/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio#demo

```
if( window.plugins && window.plugins.NativeAudio ) {

    window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex( 'music', 'audio/music.mp3', 1, 1, 0, function(msg){
    }, function(msg){
        console.log( 'error: ' + msg );
    });


    // Play
    window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop( 'music' );
}
```

Comment: If you check the // NativeAudio part on my example, I already tried your example.

It also generates a gap.

Comment: Yup, it does not support gapless audio looping.

Comment: Thus it remains only one possible "hack" : don't use the loop, and in the window.plugins.NativeAudio.play success function, you write a timeout a little shorter than your sound duration (i.e around 3750 if your music is 4s long) which relaunch the window.plugins.NativeAudio.play().

Comment: Yup, so it seems. I wonder if the gap is the same length with all devices? (250ms FOR EXAMPLE!).

Comment: For sure it will be a little "random", that's not a clean solution. You can also create a longer looped song of 4-5 min (in mp3 it won't be so heavy) and let the gap happen. If you want something clean, no choice : you'll have to hard code it.